# Character Controller For C# Need transform.translate to collide, not teleport

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am fairly new to code, I know some of the basics but my knowledge is limited, so please let me know WHY in your answer if it's not too hard to explain, I'd like to learn rather than just be given the answer!

This code is the basic controls for a game i am making. I'll be explaining the premise of the game just so you're able to better grasp what my intent is.

The game will focus on the completion of mazes, however movement is restricted to only being able to go forward, and right. You may never do a u-turn, go left or go backwards.

With my current code, it is possible (VERY EASILY POSSIBLE) to just translate over the entire maze and the colliders for walls don't apply due to it being a translate, which to my understanding is essentially 'teleporting' it.

I've looked around on similar topics and discussions but I was unable to find any answers that addressed this kind of issue with colliders.

When the object collides with a 'wall' in my maze, I want the object to be reset to it's original position, or at the very least die, I'm not sure if that will affect the answer given, but just incase keep that in mind, thank you!

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Movement_Script : MonoBehaviour {

        public float playerspeed = 1;
        void Update () {

        if(Input.GetKeyDown("up"))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 1);
        }       
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("right"))
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * 1);
            transform.Rotate(Time.deltaTime,0 ,-90);    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html or http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter.html ?

Comment: @andeart 

I have but the issue is the 'teleporting' effect I'm getting, this means i need to use a moving method, though this is a lot harder for me to get working

Answer (score 0):

When you control the transform, you are telling "Place this there".

So when you do:

```
 transform.Translate(Vector3.up * 1); // multiplying by one is useless
```

you tell to displace the object by 0,1,0 from its current position. This is regardless of any environment. You still can detect collision by it won't be resolve by the engine, you would have to do it yourself.

Unity came up with a ready to use solution with the character controller component. It does the same as you do in your code but also perform a bunch of collision checks and resolve them. The latest version is actually using rigidbody for a more physical approach.

```
http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-CharacterController.html

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.Move.html
```

the Move method is the one to use for Unity to handle the whole process for you. I would recommend to install a basic four wall room with a few boxes here and there so that you get the grip of it. Then it will be easy to move on to do whatever you want with it, whether 2D or 3D movement.

Comment: I've played around with your suggestions, but i'm coming across the same issue with my code and their code.

It's refusing to detect my colliders and just teleports right through them. I could be understanding your answer wrong this whole time and missing something obvious, but my desired effect is for the character to simply not move if there is a collider between the original position and the destination.

Also it's for a simple 2D cube to clarify!

Comment: Are you using Move method like in the link? Simply adding the CharacterController is not enough, you need to remove Translate and use Move from the CharacterController. You should copy paste the example to begin with.

Comment: Yes i copied and pasted the example and was fiddling around with code to reproduce my controls, i think i may have removed the 'move' method in trying so, I'll have another crack at it!

Comment: transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);

When using this line of code i need to define it but i'm unable to, and if i just leave it blank i'm told to assign the target variable, any suggestion on how assign it a value?

Comment: using transform.position is the same as transform.Translate. If you do a right click ->Go to definition on Translate you will see that it is just a wrapper around transform.position. You need to use Move on the CharacterController component. This method will move (as it says) and also consider collision.